# Libft bonus rule relinks

Tags: makefile

So, right now my Makefile looks like this

```
SRCS    = (let's say there are some .c files)

BONUS_SRCS  = (and there are some _bonus.c files)

OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

BONUS_OBJS = $(BONUS_SRCS:.c=.o)

HDRS    = libft.h

NAME    = libft.a

RM  = rm -rf

GCC = gcc

AR  = ar -crs

FLAGS   = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

.c.o:
            $(GCC) $(FLAGS) -I includes -c $< -o $(<:.c=.o)

$(NAME):    $(OBJS) $(HDRS)
            $(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJS)

all:        $(NAME)

bonus:      $(OBJS) $(BONUS_OBJS) $(HDRS)
            $(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(BONUS_OBJS)

re:         clean fclean all

clean:
            $(RM) $(OBJS) $(BONUS_OBJS)

fclean:     clean
            $(RM) $(NAME)
.PHONY:
            all clean fclean re bonus
```

And if I try to `make bonus` make compiles bonus functions at first, and every other `make bonus` relinks. Is there any way to tell make not to relink?

By "relink" I mean recreating the libft.a every time I call `make bonus`.

Example `make`:

```
$> make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I includes -c test_a.c -o test_a.o
ar -crs libft.a test_a.o
$> make
make: `libft.a' is up to date.
$>
```

But `make bonus`:

```
$> make bonus
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I includes -c test_a.c -o test_a.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I includes -c test_b.c -o test_b.o
ar -crs libft.a test_a.o test_b.o
$> make bonus
ar -crs libft.a test_a.o test_b.o
$>
```

And this is confusing as hell.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "relinks".  `make bonus` won't link anything, from what I can tell.  Without knowing what these variables are set to or understanding what the behavior is, there's little we can say.  If you show (cut and paste please) the commands you typed and the output you got and why you think it's wrong we might be able to help.

Comment: I'm sorry, first time. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not confusing if you remember that make doesn't have some magic database of information about what it did last time.  It has your makefile, and it has the files on the filesystem (and the last modified time that the filesystem tracks).

So when you run `make bonus`, make looks for a rule that knows how to build the target `bonus` and finds this rule:

```
bonus: $(OBJS) $(BONUS_OBJS) $(HDRS)
        $(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(BONUS_OBJS)
```

This rule tells make that if it runs this recipe the target `bonus` will be updated.  Make sees that the target `bonus` does not exist (there's no file named `bonus` on the disk) so it decides that target is out of date and needs to be updated.

But, of course, your recipe does **NOT** update the target `bonus`; `bonus` is not created or updated by this recipe at all.

So, the next time you run `make bonus` make again looks for a file named `bonus`, it still doesn't exist, so make again uses the recipe you told it would update that target.  And on and on.

Check out Paul's Second [Rule of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).

Answer (score 0):

It should work to adjust your makefile as following

```
.PHONY: bonus
bonus: $(NAME)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding bonus to .PHONY and $(NAME) to bonus didn't do the thing. Actually these actions led to extra step for `bonus` rule, and it creates standard lib at first, and then creates new lib with _bonus functions. Every other `make bonus` still recreates libft.a

Comment: Should move dependencies and actions from bonus to $(NAME). Make sure no any action is taken for bonus.